# What are the steps to invoke a Java Project's ANT job using Jenkins Freestyle Project Job, when both are present on the same server ( machine)?

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

**Current Setup**

1. I have Jenkins installed on serverA.
2. I have a Java Project with an Ant script ( build.xml ) file present on serverA.

**Question Details:**

I would like to understand what is the easiest way I can configure a Jenkins freestyle project to invoke the Java project's ant job.

I understand that there are multiple ways to get around this, like using jenkins ANT plugin, and others, but I am searching for simple solution to start with.
I am open for suggestions though.

P.S.:
I have searched over internet, and most of the examples are using git or other SCM repositories to point to ant script.
I am comparatively new to Jenkins and ANT jobs.

Comment: You should be using a source control tool.like git. The scm path to repo can be a filepath. You alao waant to have Jenkins build in a disposable workspace separate to where you development, hence the usefulness for source control tool. Also, best practice is Jenkins has a server controller plus agent node executor for jobs (can be co-located, but should run under separate accts).

Comment: Thanks Ian, I will try your recommendation to use some SCM tool.